# Wet vs dry sand

Tags: homework-and-exercises, density

I'm trying to figure out the density of dry sand and wet sand. The problem that I am having is that the dry sand seems to be denser than the wet sand, which can't be right. What I have done is filled up a $500 \mathrm{\,mL}$ beaker with water and placed $100\mathrm{\,g}$ of dry sand inside. The beaker then read $520 \mathrm{\,mL}$, hence $100\mathrm{\,g}$ of dry sand has a volume of $20 \mathrm{\,mL}$. Then, I mixed sand with water and used $100 \mathrm{\,g}$ of that in another $500 \mathrm{\,mL}$ of water. The beaker then read $580 \mathrm{\,mL}$, meaning that $100\mathrm{\,g}$ of wet sand has a volume of $80 \mathrm{\,mL}$.  So, if you use $p=\frac{m}{v}$, dry sand has a density of $5000\mathrm{\,kg/m^3}$ and wet sand only $1250 \mathrm{\,kg/m^3}$. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: There is empty space between particles of sand.

Comment: A beaker is a container.  If you fill up  a 500ml container with anything, how can it read 520ml?  Do you mean you first filled a large beaker with 500ml of something?

Comment: Have you tried measuring the density of *actual* dry sand, i.e. not mixing it with water?

Comment: I put the 100g of dry sand in a latex wrapper, so the actual sand did not get wet

Comment: There's an easier way to do this.  Determine the mass of an empty 500 ml beaker.  Then, fill a 500 ml beaker with dry sand, and mass it.  Calculate the mass of the sand by difference.  Then, carefully pour water into the beaker full of sand until no more water will fit.  Mass the beaker full of wet sand and calculate the mass of the wet sand by difference.  You now have the volumes and masses to calculate the unknown densities.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculations show that solid grains of sand (ie excluding the space between the grains) has a density of 5 g/cc whereas a mixture of sand and water has a density of 1.25 g/cc. That seems reasonable to me.